# Overheating Problem

Tags: drivers, ati, kubuntu, overheating

Hello Ubuntu comunity.

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP notebook (i7 2.0 ghz, 4gb memory ram) and I'm noticing that my computer temperature is rising up to 90-96º Celcius within the first half hour that I start running Ubuntu.

- Not so long ago I cleaned up the fan and on Windows, my notebook does not overheat. Dust is not the problem.
- There doesnt seem to be a process consuming a lot of resources.
- I had the same problem before with Lubuntu and Kubuntu. With Kubuntu after an update, it got miraculously fixed.

I belive its a video card driver problem,I tried to install the drivers manually from the website (I got a Ati Radeon HD 6770) but failed on the installation process (It goes unresponsive when trying to install).

**Edit 1 :** Result of doing a `lspci -nn | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler XT [AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series] [1002:6740]
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: dual graphics/ hybrid / switchable GPU?

Comment: can you provide the output of top when your temperature is high?

Comment: Web-E I have no idea. How can I find out and why is it relevant?

Comment: jasmines dont know exactly what you mean. And output of top?..

Comment: By the way if I go to "About this computer", then "Graphics" it shoes as "Drivers : uknown"

Answer (score 0):

I gave up. I reinstalled Kubuntu and itś working like a charm. Its a shame though, I really wanted to try Ubuntu... thanks anyway for the help.